# How to keep no grouped columns in a groupedBy in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, in `pandas`, that I want to group by **email**, get the max value for **date** and keep the **status** column. But the **status** is not used on the `groupby`.

Example: give the follow dataframe df

```
+-------------------------------+
|  email  |  status  |   date   |
+-------------------------------+
|  test1  |  viewed  | 01/07/18 |
---------------------------------
|  test1  |not viewed| 03/07/18 | 
---------------------------------
|  test2  |not viewed| 02/07/18 |
---------------------------------
|  test2  |  viewed  | 01/07/18 | 
---------------------------------
|  test3  |not viewed| 03/07/18 |
---------------------------------
|  test3  |  viewed  | 04/07/18 |
---------------------------------
```

I use the following code, but I want to keep the status column, but I don't know how.

```
df.groupby([email]).aggregate({'date': max})
```

Desired output:

```
+-------------------------------+
|  email  |  status  |   date   |
+-------------------------------+    
|  test1  |not viewed| 03/07/18 | 
---------------------------------
|  test2  |not viewed| 02/07/18 | 
---------------------------------
|  test3  |  viewed  | 04/07/18 |
---------------------------------
```

In sum, I want to group by **email**, get the most recent **date** and keep the **status** column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `agg` You could sort by date, use a `groupby`, and select the last one (which will be the most recent):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.sort_values('date').groupby('email', as_index=False).last()

   email      status       date
0  test1  not viewed 2018-03-07
1  test2  not viewed 2018-02-07
2  test3      viewed 2018-04-07
```

Comment: I could adjust my business logic and resolve the problem with other approach. But you answer was very helpful. Ty.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can using `drop_duplicates`

```
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates(['email'],keep='last')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of the maximum date for each group and then subset the original `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.loc[df.groupby('email').date.idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
   email      status       date
1  test1  not viewed 2018-03-07
2  test2  not viewed 2018-02-07
5  test3      viewed 2018-04-07
```